# UISearchController not searching in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have set up a UISearchController as a header for my tableview with the following code:

```
let mySearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    let keywords = searchBar.text
    let finalKeywords = keywords?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")

    searchUrl = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=\(finalKeywords!)&type=track&limit=20"
    print(searchUrl)

    callAlamo(url: searchUrl)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(postCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    tableView.separatorColor = .red

    mySearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    mySearchController.delegate = self as? UISearchControllerDelegate
    tableView.tableHeaderView = mySearchController.searchBar

}
```

I adde a breakpoint at the searchBarButtonClicked function and at the print(searchUrl) inside of the function, but it never went to the breakpoints. Why is the searchBarSearchButtonClicked function not executing when I click on the search bar?

Comment: Why are you casting `self` as UISearchControllerDelegate? This downcast is probably returning `nil`.  You don't need the downcast if you have added implemented `UISearchControllerDelegate` in your class.

Comment: I deleted `mySearchController.delegate = self as? UISearchControllerDelegate` but it still does not work

Comment: You need to have a delegate and you need to set your class as the delegate, but I am wondering why you have a conditional downcast to set the delegate; it makes me think that you haven't set up the delegate implementation properly, which is why the delegate method isn't being called.

Comment: Here is how I set up the class: `class SongSearchTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate`. What else is needed to set up the delegate?

Comment: That should do it.  What happens if you delete the `as? UISearchControllerDelegate` from the `mySearchController.delegate = self` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the wrong delegate.  A `UISearchBarController` as a delegate property, but the method you are implementing is a `UISearchBarDelegate` method, so you need to set your object as the delegate for the search bar contained within the `UISearchBarController:

```
mySearchController.searchBar.delegate = self
```

Comment: Normally you would implement `searchBar(textDidChange:)` and perform a search as the user types.   Use a timer so that the search is only performed when the user stops typing for a half second

Comment: How would I implement a timer inside of the textDidChange function?